# error in embedded conditional expression

Tags: r

I have a conditional expression that when it is satisfied (==7) by the result of a function (VitPath$states) implies the summation of other embedded conditional expressions when their conditions (<0.1) are also satisfied resulting in G

```
G<-if(tail(VitPath$states,1)==7) 
{if(summary(ResFit)$coef[370]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[64]*summary(ResFit)$coef[91]   
else 0 + 
if(summary(ResFit)$coef[371]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[65]*summary(ResFit)$coef[93] 
else 0 +  
if(summary(ResFit)$coef[372]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[66]*summary(ResFit)$coef[95] 
else 0 + 
if(summary(ResFit)$coef[373]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[67]*summary(ResFit)$coef[97]    
else 0 +   
if(summary(ResFit)$coef[374]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[68]*summary(ResFit)$coef[99]   
else 0 + 
if(summary(ResFit)$coef[375]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[69]*summary(ResFit)$coef[101] 
else 0 + 
if(summary(ResFit)$coef[376]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[70]*summary(ResFit)$coef[103] 
else 0 + 
if(summary(ResFit)$coef[377]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[71]*summary(ResFit)$coef[105] 
else 0 +
if(summary(ResFit)$coef[378]<0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[72]*summary(ResFit)$coef[107]   
else 0} else 0
```

It seems that the embedded conditional expressions are not properly expresed as it produces an error in the first embedded expression as it seem not to understand the multiplication.

```
Computing the asymptotic covariance matrix of estimates
Error en if (summary(ResFit)$coef[370] < 0.1) summary(ResFit)$coef[64] *  : 
valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
```

Is there a way to do this without changing the present format. When I place a parenthesis or brakets (summary(ResFit)$coef[71]*summary(ResFit)$coef[105]) it also does not work.

Many thanks

EDITED

ResFit is produced by the following expression X beeing a vector of numeric values

```
ResFit = HMMFit(X, nStates=9, control=list(init="KMEANS"))
```

Comment: You want `ifelse`, not `if` and `else`.

Comment: Thank you and how do I place the 0 after each embedded conditional

Comment: You want something like `G <- ifelse(CONDITION, VALUEIFTRUE, 0) + ifelse(...) + ifelse(...) + ...`

Comment: Thomas thanks, the first condition defines if satisfied that the following conditional expressions should be computed. The first expression is independent of the ones embedded if the first expression condition is satisfied

Comment: It looks like you've gone wild with copy and paste, which makes this difficult to read; I think including `beta <- coef(ResFit);` and refactoring would make your question quite a bit clearer.

Comment: What does not work is the multiplication with in the conditional if as considers incorrectly True and False and as there more elements then it does not work. I could go in doing the multiplication externally, but would like to embedd it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It's a Boolean algebra version; When the test fails, the result will be 0 but when it success it will be the product. I assume you only want the first column of the summary coef matrix since multiplying teh standard errors would not make much sense:

```
  G<-if(tail(VitPath$states,1)==7) {  summary(ResFit)$coef[370:378,1]<0.1 )*
                            ( summary(ResFit)$coef[64:72,1])*(summary(ResFit)$coef[91:107,1]) }
```

This should be much faster, as well as being clearer and easier to maintain. If you are using a modeling function different than `lm`, you should post further details. I was assuming the structure returned from the `$coef`-call would be like:

coefficients
a p x 4 matrix with columns for the estimated coefficient, its standard error, t-statistic and corresponding (two-sided) p-value. Aliased coefficients are omitted.

Comment: Thank you, I got the concept and tried to implement your sugestion but it produces an error related to summary(ResFit)$coef[370:378,1]<0.1 it seems not to accept it - Error en summary(ResFit)$coef[442:450, 1] : 
subíndice fuera de  los límites. Would not be adequate to use seq in this context

Comment: Post the output of `str(summary(ResFit)$coef )` as an edit to your question body. You never showed how you constructed ResFit so we are just guessing at its structure.

Comment: Yes I think is a good idea, on another hand why not keep the structure of the question (even if it could be made more effective by sequencing etc) and if it exists find a way to make the true or false part (the multiplication) work.